# How to Unproject and Reproject Vertices of a Polygon in openlayers with Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers, polygon

I wanting to reproject the vertices of my polygon. I have been able to achieve this for the bounds but having a bit of trouble with the vertices.

```
           function onFeatureModified(event) {
           var bounds = event.feature.geometry.getBounds();
           var answer = "bottom: " + bounds.bottom + "\n";
           answer += "left: " + bounds.left + "\n";
           answer += "right: " + bounds.right + "\n";
           answer += "top: " + bounds.top + "\n";
           alert(answer);

           var mapProjv =  map.getProjectionObject();
           var epsg4326v = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
       var verticesNative = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices();
       var verticesLatLon = verticesNative.transform( mapProjv , epsg4326v  );
       var vertices = verticesNative;
           alert(verticesNative);
           }
```

Below code that works:

```
           var vertices = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices();
           alert(vertices);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getVertices()` method returns an array of `OpenLayers.Geometry.Point` objects, so you can't call `transform()` method on it. What you should do instead is to loop through array and call `transform()` on each object like that:

```
var vertices = event.features[0].geometry.getVertices();
var transformedVertices = [];
for(var i=0; i < vertices.length; i++){
    transformedVertices.push(vertices[i].transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    ));
}

//create new feature with transformed vertices
```